# filestream in Assembly - emu8086

Tags: assembly, filestream

I made a code recently, that ask the user's `Name`, `Address`, `StudentID` and `Contact Number`. My code can currently store only **one** record. What my teacher requires is I use `Filestream` to store them in a `.txt` file and store **multiple records**, not just **one** - which is my case. Here is my current working code (you can get the .asm file at the end):

```
data segment
; add your data here!
msgLabel db "/**Initial Draft of CMPSC 122 Project. King Garrett Goting, BSCS 2A**\",10,13,"/**Can currently accomodate ONE record**\",10,13," ",10,13,"$"

clear db  "                                                                       ",10,13
       db  "                                         ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                                     ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13
       db  "                                   ",10,13

       db  "                                  $"

msgChoice db "= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = ="
          db 10,13,"LIBRARY BORROWING FORM"
          db 10,13,"[1] - Add barrower"
          db 10,13,"[2] - Show list of barrowers"
          db 10,13,"[x] - Exit" 
          db 10,13,"Choice: $"

msgName db 10,13,"Please enter your name: $"
msgAdd  db 10,13,"Your address please: $"
msgStudID db 10,13,"Student ID please: $"
msgContact db 10,13,"Contact Number: $" 

getName db 100 dup  (' ')
getAdd db 100 dup  (' ')
getID db 100 dup  (' ')
getCt db 100 dup  (' ') 

newl db 10,13,'$'                         
msgError db 10,13,"1 record can only be recorded at the moment$"
confrmName db 10,13, "Name: $"
confrmID db 10,13,"Student ID: $" 
confrmAdd db 10,13,"Address: $"
confrmCt db 10,13,"Contact Number: $"
ty db 10,13,"Thanks for using the initial draft!$" 
error db 10,13,"Invalid choice!$" 

labelAdd db 10,13,"* * * A D D   R E C O R D * * *$"
labelShow db 10,13,"* * * S H O W   R E C O R D / S * * *$" 

promt db 10,13,10,13,"Press any key to proceed...$"

ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax



jmp home
invalid:
    lea dx, error
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 

    lea dx, newl
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    jmp home

home:
    call clrscr:
        mov ah,3
        int 10h 

    lea dx, msgLabel
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    lea dx, msgChoice
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    cmp al, '1' 
    je AddBarrower


    cmp al, '2'
    je ShowList 


    cmp al, 'x'
    je endz 


cmp al, '1'
jne invalid

cmp al, '2'
jne invalid

cmp al, 'x'
jne invalid

again:

AddBarrower:     
    call clrscr:
        mov ah,3
        int 10h

    lea dx, labelAdd
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    lea dx, newl
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    lea dx, msgName
    mov ah,9
    int 21h  

    mov dx, offset getName
    mov si, 0
    loopName:
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h           
        mov getName[si], al
        inc si
        cmp al, 13
        jne loopName
        mov getName[si-1], '$'

   lea dx, msgAdd
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

   mov dx, offset getAdd
   mov si, 0

   loopAdd:
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov getAdd[si], al
        inc si
        cmp al, 13
        jne loopAdd
        mov getAdd[si-1], '$'

   lea dx, msgStudID      
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

   mov dx, offset getID
   mov si, 0

   loopID:
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov getID[si], al
        inc si
        cmp al, 13
        jne loopID 
        mov getID[si-1], '$'

   lea dx, msgContact
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

   mov dx, offset getCt
   mov si, 0

   loopContact:
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov getCt[si], al
        inc si
        cmp al, 13
        jne loopContact
        mov getCt[si-1], '$' 

        lea dx, newl
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h  


   lea dx, promt
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

   mov ah, 1
   int 21h

   jmp home

   ShowList:
        call clrscr:
            mov ah,3
            int 10h   

        lea dx, labelShow
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        lea dx, newl
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        lea dx, confrmName
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset getName            
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h 

        lea dx, confrmAdd
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset getAdd
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        lea dx, confrmID
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset getID
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        lea dx, confrmCt
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        mov dx, offset getCt
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        lea dx, promt
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        mov ah, 1
        int 21h


        jmp home






; wait for any key....
endz:
lea dx, ty
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov ah, 1
int 21h


mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
int 21h    


ends

clrscr proc
mov bx,0000h
mov ah, 2
mov dl,0
mov dh,0
int 10h
lea dx, clear

mov ah, 9
int 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl,0
mov dh,0
int 10h
ret
endp
end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

[Here's](https://www.mediafire.com/?8xqijcbgjg9k635) the .asm file if you ever need it. :)
You have my gratitude.

Comment: What does "using FileStream" mean in this context?  He want you to interface with a c++ runtime library?  You are already using DOS interrupts.  Can't you just use int 21h al=3dh to open a file and int 21h al=40h to write to it?

Comment: sir @DavidWohlferd, what he wants us is to put the records in a `.txt` file. Can you care to explain where sould I put those in my code sir? Because he did not taught those to us :(